# Creating 20 million records in Core Data from CSV - macOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-data

I am building a database from a large CSV (4GB) to work on locally for myself, this will not be a production app. I will only have one model / entity to begin with that contains 8-9 attributes that are mostly strings and a handful of Int's. I will have around 20 million records to store. I will only write the database from this CSV once and from then it will receive incremental updates to add or amend roughly 50,000 records per month. I will be querying the database fairly frequently but only as a single user.

Is Core Data the correct choice for this scenario? I understand that it is an object graph and not just a database, I have a 16GB ram iMac and a 8GB Macbook pro and I am unsure how much of a memory constraint this may be while using Core Data. I am trying to figure out if I would be better off using SQLite or if Core Data is the correct tool for the job.

If Core Data is a good choice for this use case then I could use some help on structuring the creation of records without constraining myself on ram. As far as I  understand I should write entities to a child context and when I am ready to copy to disk I will pass the data from the child context to its parent context (memory to memory) and then the parent can write/flush to disk.

This is how I would visualise the process, I will only use one attribute on an entity the example.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { //Non blocking
    //iterate line by line over csv reader never exceeds 9.1MB takes 30 mins. I will look into chunking to better utilise multithreading later.
    for (index, row) in reader.enumerated()  {
        let person = Person(entity: personEntity, insertInto: backgroundContext)
        person.setValue(row[0], forKey: "name")

        //When I hit x iterations or x seconds since last save - save to disk and clear the ram for the context 
        backgroundContext.perform {
            do {
                try backgroundContext.save() //I beleive pushes changes only to its parent context?
               //Clear background context ram (of stored records) 

               // Main context should now write to disk and then it should also clear its ram
              //do {
                  //main context work
             //} catch {

             //}
            } catch {
                //error handling 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a couple of concerns which stem from me not clearly understanding the Core Data structure.

1)  After saving to persistent storage from the main context I want to make sure the main context can flush those records from ram. I don't want to clear all records in ram as the main context may have been written to from the background context while the main context was writing to disk (effectively data loss).

2) Similar to point 1, when the background context saves I want to make sure the background context only clears records from ram that were saved to its parent context.

If anyone can shed some light on the situation or provide some examples of correct structure it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think that `reset()` function of `NSManagedObjectContext` class is what you are looking for.

But I really think that you are using CoreData in a wrong, I would propose you to init CoreData with prepared .sqlite file (created from CSV). It will work better and much faster than creating instances of `NSManagedObject` and saving them to the context manually.